# Run in Virtual working properly, but when build apk can't work

Tags: android

I was wondering when I run in virtual demode my game working properly and when I build apk it's not work and I check the LogCat showing as bellow error:

```
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549): ExecutionException
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x7f020947
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.Resources.clearRCCachedDrawableLocked(Resources.java:3023)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.Resources.mClearALDCLocked(Resources.java:3007)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:2985)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.app.ResourcesManager.applyConfigurationToResourcesLocked(ResourcesManager.java:494)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4784)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4737)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1585)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x7f020947
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.Resources$RCCallable.call(Resources.java:1186)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.Resources$RCCallable.call(Resources.java:1160)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:422)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  at android.content.res.Resources$RCCallable.call(Resources.java:1179)
06-12 12:05:41.580: E/Resources(6549):  ... 5 more
```

I do appreciated for your kindly help. I was stuck in 2 weeks already :'(

Comment: is it a regular app? seems your resource not packed well in your apk.

Comment: Yes. do you have way to solve this problem, sir?